# ¿Cómo simplicar un switch que contiene otros switch en cada uno de sus casos a base de funciones virtuales? C#

Tags: c#, switch

Estoy haciendo un manejador de eventos y se me está haciendo una clase gigante y muy repetitiva. Lo cual me hace pensar que debe existir una forma de simplificar las cosas.

Tengo un switch principal y en cada caso de ese switch hay otro switch. Me gustaría que todos los casos de ambos switch hubiera una función virtual que se pudiera implementar desde las clases derivadas pero estoy teniendo algunos problemas para conseguirlo.

A continuación el código que estoy implementando para que se vea mejor el problema.

Todo empieza con estas dos enumeraciones:

```
public enum Property { get, lost, start, end, update, none };
public enum Type { hit, health, lives, respawn, game, dead, score, coins, tokens, power, weapon, armor};
```

Cada tipo de evento tiene mas o menos las mismas propiedads con lo que empezé a implementarlo así

```
   switch (eventType)
    {
        case EntityEvent.Type.hit:
            {
                switch (property)
                {
                    case Property.get:
                        break;
                    case Property.lost:
                        break;
                    case Property.start:
                        break;
                    case Property.end:
                        break;
                    case Property.update:
                        break;
                    case Property.none:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }                
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Como pueden ver es algo terrible grande y repetitivo cuando se quiere hacer con todos los casos.

El tema es que además me gustaría que cada caso fuese implementado por clases derivadas mediante funciones virtuales. Algo tal que asi:

```
public class EventListener : MonoBehaviour, IEventListener
{
    public virtual void Listen(EventInfo info, EntityEvent.Type eventType, Property property)
    {

        switch (eventType)
        {            
            case EntityEvent.Type.health:
            {
                OnHealth(info, property);
                break;
            }
        default:
            break;
        }
     }
 }

    //--------------------------------------------------
    public void OnHealth(EventInfo info, Property property)
    {
        switch (property)
        {
            case Property.get:
                OnHealthGet(info);
                break;
            case Property.lost:
                OnHealthGet(info);
                break;
            case Property.start:
                break;
            case Property.end:
                break;
            case Property.update:
                OnHealthUpdate(info);
                break;
            case Property.none:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------
    public virtual void OnHealthGet(EventInfo info) { }
    public virtual void OnHealthLost(EventInfo info) { }
    public virtual void OnHealthUpdate(EventInfo info) { }
    //--------------------------------------------------
```

Pero sigo viendo que hay un mismo patrón que se repite y hace que la clase cada vez sea mas grande...

He intentado hacer esta otra clase para ver si consigo simplificar las cosas y reducir el tamaño.

```
//--------------------------------------------------
public class PropertyEventManager : EventManager
{
    public EntityEvent.Type eventType;//hay que especifiar el tipo de evento al que pertenece
                                      

    public override void OnEventProperty(EventInfo info, EntityEvent.Type eventType, Property property) 
    {
        if (this.eventType != eventType)  return;//con esto el primer switch no tiene razón de ser

        switch (property)
        {
            case Property.get:
                {
                    OnGet(info);
                    break;
                }
            case Property.lost:
                {
                    OnLost(info);
                    break;
                }
            case Property.start:
                {
                    OnStart(info);
                    break;
                }
            case Property.end:
                {
                    OnEnd(info);
                    break;
                }
            case Property.update:
                {
                    OnUpdate(info);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------
    public virtual void OnGet(EventInfo info) { }
    public virtual void OnLost(EventInfo info) { }
    public virtual void OnStart(EventInfo info) { }
    public virtual void OnEnd(EventInfo info) { }
    public virtual void OnUpdate(EventInfo info) { }
    //--------------------------------------------------
}
```

**El problema es que ahora no veo la forma de meter esto dentro de su caso correspondiente**
Se me queda algo asi:

```
    public virtual void Listen(EventInfo info, EntityEvent.Type eventType, Property property)
    {
        OnEventProperty(info, eventType, property);//-->asi funciona pero es demasiado ambiguo para implemntar en la clase derivada

        switch (eventType)
        {             
            case EntityEvent.Type.health:
            {
                OnHealth(info, property);//--> `me gustaria meterlo aquí`                    
                break;
            }                    
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Pues ese es el problema. Me gustaría poder implementar esas funciones en clases derivadas. Que estén todas en el lugar que le corresponden, sin ambigüedades y a la vez no tener miles de switch en una clase gigantesca.
¿Alguna idea de como puede hacerlo?
Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he hecho asi... mas o menos conseguí lo que quería... o al menos conseguí reducirlo todo a una sola línea y no tener una clase gigante.

```
    //--------------------------------------------------
    public delegate void Delegate(EventInfo info);
    //--------------------------------------------------
    public void OnProperty(EventInfo info, Property property, 
        Delegate OnGet, Delegate OnLost, Delegate OnStart, Delegate OnEnd, Delegate OnUpdate)
    {
        switch (property)
        {
            case Property.get:
                OnGet(info);
                break;
            case Property.lost:
                OnLost(info);
                break;
            case Property.start:
                OnStart(info);
                break;
            case Property.end:
                OnEnd(info);
                break;
            case Property.update:
                OnUpdate(info);
                break;
            case Property.none:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }    

    //--------------------------------------------------
    public virtual void OnHealth(EventInfo info, Property property)
    {
        OnProperty(info, property, OnHealthGet, OnHealthLost, OnHealthStart, OnHealthEnd, OnHealthUpdate);
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------
    public virtual void OnHealthGet(EventInfo info) { }
    public virtual void OnHealthLost(EventInfo info) { }
    public virtual void OnHealthUpdate(EventInfo info) { }
    public virtual void OnHealthStart(EventInfo info) { }
    public virtual void OnHealthEnd(EventInfo info) { }
    //--------------------------------------------------
```

Aún estoy abierto a otras posibilidades. Si alguien me da una solución mejor que esta le daré la respuesta por valida!! Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Tal vez un arreglo de punteros a funciones?  La enumeración es un integer, Al principio, pone los punteros en el arreglo, y entonces en lugar de "case (property)", escribe algo como "NosVamosA[property](info);;"

Comment: Gracias por la idea!! No me pasarías un link o algo donde pueda ver un ejemplo de eso que dices?... Estoy empezando con C# hay un montón de cosas que me suenan a chino todavia!! XD Saludos!!

Comment: No podía encontrar ningún ejemplo en español, pero en inglés, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712137/array-containing-methods y https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c08a0d0-58e4-4df6-b6d3-75e785fff8a8/array-of-function-pointers?forum=csharplanguage parecen demonstrar lo que quiere.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Duston!!